# AS3: how to convert a string to a DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3

This is driving me crazy.

In `Main.as` I have a **button** that, when pressed, trigger some stuff.
In `arrayTambores` I define an array with some `Strings` in it.

What I want to achieve is to create a big `movieclip` container with several `mc` inside, whose names are picked from that array.

Thanks you guys!

So this is what I have in `ArrayTambores`:

```
package 
{
    public class arrayTambores
    {
        public static var tempArray: Array = new Array();
        public static var bigArrayTambor1: Array = new Array();
        public static var randomPos:Number = 0;
        public static var a:int = 0;
        public static var z:int = 0;


        tempArray[0] = "heladeraIcon";
        tempArray[1] = "comodinIcon";

        for (a = 0; a < 2; a++)
        {
            tempArray.unshift("microondasIcon");
        }

        for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            tempArray.unshift("duchaIcon");
        }


        bigArrayTambor1.length = tempArray.length;

        for (var z: int = 0; z < bigArrayTambor1.length; z++)
        {
            randomPos = int(Math.random() * tempArray.length);
            bigArrayTambor1[z] = tempArray.splice(randomPos,1)[0];
        }

        public function arrayTambores()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Main.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Main():void
        {
            var Tambor1_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();//This is the container mc

        /*I already convert some bitmaps to movieclips in my Library, and assign each of one a class name. I.e., for the var comodinIcon, the class to the comodin.jpg in the Library is comodin. And of course I set each one to Export for ActionScript and Export in frame 1.*/

        var comodinIcon:comodin = new comodin();
        var duchaIcon:ducha = new ducha();
        var heladeraIcon:heladera = new heladera();
        var microondasIcon:microondas = new microondas();


        // BUTTON
        makeButton(my_mc, my_mc_click);

        function my_mc_click(evt: MouseEvent):void
        {

            Tambor1_mc.x = 132;
            Tambor1_mc.y = 250;


            var clipA1:String = new String();
            clipA1 = arrayTambores.bigArrayTambor1[0];
            // HERE is where it fails, because it can´t convert clipA1, which is a String, //to a flash.display.DisplayObject

            Tambor1_mc.addChild(DisplayObject(clipA1));

            stage.addChild(Tambor1_mc);
        }
        function makeButton(which_mc: MovieClip, clickFunction: Function):void
        {
            which_mc.buttonMode = true;
            which_mc.useHandCursor = true;
            which_mc.mouseChildren = false;
            which_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickFunction);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're thinking about names and assignments backwards. Try something like Tambores.bigArrayTambor1[0].name = clipA1

Comment: How do your string names correlate to your library objects?   Do you have objects in your library with class names (exported for actionscript) - or are they existing instances on the timeline?     What is supposed to happen in your `my_mc_click` function?

Comment: @ Neal thank you, I´ll try that in a minute :)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis, thank you for your comment: yes, my jpgs are in my Library, I converted to mc and create a class with export parameters. They don´t have an instance on the stage, though... I just want them in the Library to call them through a variable from inside the Main.as

Comment: @Neal, I try your suggestion: 

    var clipA1;
    arrayTambores.bigArrayTambor1[0].name = clipA1;
    Tambor1_mc.addChild(clipA1);

but it says **error 1056 cannot create property name in string**, which leads me to the original problem: how to convert that string I retrieve from the array bigArrayTambor1 as my Class name... Thanks, any idea will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer makes the assumption that you have two library objects with 'export for actionscript' enabled and class names of `heladeraIcon` & `comodinIcon`.

To instantiate those in your code, you can't use strings because AS3 doesn't reference classes via strings (Though you can obtain a Class reference from a string using `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName()` but that isn't necessary here).

You actually just reference them by whatever value you put in as the class, so in your case `heladeraIcon` (no quotes because it's not a string, it's a class). When you check Export for actionscript, that class name becomes available in your program just like built-in classes.

So your code should look something like this:

```
        tempArray[0] = heladeraIcon; //match whatever you put in the library object's properties as the class name
        tempArray[1] = comodinIcon;
```

---

```
        //you have get a reference to the class
        var clipClass:Class = arrayTambores.bigArrayTambor1[0] as Class;

        //then instantiate that class
        var clipA1:DisplayObject = (new clipClass()) as DisplayObject;

        Tambor1_mc.addChild(clipA1);
        stage.addChild(Tambor1_mc);
```

---

Here is an example how to properly setup your library object(s) with AS3 Class linkage:

1. In Flash/AnimateCC, right-click (or ctrl+click on Mac) your symbol and choose `properties`.
2. In the properties window, check the `Export for ActionScript` & `Export in frame 1` checkboxes in the *ActionScript Linkage* section.
3. Also in the *ActionScript Linkage* section, enter in a unique class name (in this example I've put in `MyCustomClass`.
4. Close the properties window.

In the library, you should now see the Class name that was given under the Linkage column.  Keep in mind, the object name and Class/Linkage name can be different.

Now with the above linkage setup, I can do the following:

```
var clipClass:Class = MyCustomClass;
var clipA1:DisplayObject = (new clipClass()) as DisplayObject;
addChild(clipA1);
```

[image: screenshot showing linkage settings]

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation, BadFeelingAboutThis. It totally makes sense, and looks like an elegant solution that I´d never could arrived to by myself. I must be doing something wrong, though, because I get this error message after applying your code: **Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor**. I could make it work using this: 

    clipA1 = arrayTambores.bigArrayTambor1[a];
    var tempClass = getDefinitionByName(clipA1) as Class;
    var tempmc = new tempClass();
    Tambor1_mc.addChild(tempmc);

(continue)

Comment: I´m sure it´s not as neat as your solution, and I´m really lost here, because all my bets would go to what you wrote as the best possible code... as I said, I´m sure there must be wrong things with my code that prevent your code to work as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have quotes on the class name?  like this: `tempArray[0] = heladeraIcon;`  NOT this `tempArray[0] = "heladeraIcon";` and that the name matches exactly what's in your actionscript linkage?  See my updated answer for proper linkage

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I think I have my files exactly as your attached images (I made a screen capture, but I don`t think I can attach it in a comment)